# Development and Production environment have different behaviour with the same setup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, iis, odbc

I've developed a web application with asp.net/vb.net using Visual Studio 2012. I've this application locally on my computer and on a server where is accessible from the web. Now, i've just a problem with the ODBC.

In my local version i get this error when i try to access a databace with an odbc:

```
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

And it's ok, because visual studio it's a 32bit application and i don't have the 32bit odbc.

But, in my production environment i don't have the 32bit odbc too but i don't get the error and everything works good.

I really don't understand why.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Every Windows x64 architecture has both 32 and 64 bit ODBC. You can manage the ODBC for 64 bit in `[Unit]:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` and for 32 bit in `[Unit]:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

Try to create the DSN in the correct ODBC depending on your application based platform. You can check it on `Visual Studio > Your Application > Properties > Compile tab > Platform`

Comment: As i said: in the production environment i dont have the 32bit odbc and the application works right. In the development environment i get the error. In the "platform" option i can choose only "Any CPU".

Comment: If you don't have the 32 bit ODBC (i don't know how is possible) in your production environment ant it's working fine, that means the app is using the 64 bit ODBC. Try to force it to be built for a x86 architecture. To add x86 to target platform, please go to `Build menu > Configuration Manager > select Active Solution platform > New`. Then in the coming New Solution Platform dialog, choose `x86`  from the first drop-down box > `OK`